# WiX tool packaging, avoid ovewrite file on major upgrade

Tags: service, wix, uninstallation

I have a problem with WiX when I try to generate an MSI (WiX v3.11).

My product is a windows service that must be installed, and during this installation process, I launch a form that collects information for connection to database. This information is stored in a .config file that is installed in the same application folder.

The problem is that if I do an update of the package, I must keep the configuration file, but if I uninstall the application, it should delete the configuration file.

The configuration file can be modified after or during installation.

```
<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" />        

<ComponentGroup Id="ConfigFiles" Directory="INSTALL_SERVICE">
    <Component Id="ConfigFile"  Guid="11FDDC05-F4D2-4418-82E8-0CB3B3784300" Win64="$(var.Win64)" NeverOverwrite="yes" >
        <File Id="F.config" Name="service.config" DiskId="1" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes"  Source="..\Resources\service.config" />
        <RemoveFile Id="CleanUpLogFile" On="uninstall" Name="service.config"/>
    </Component> 
</ComponentGroup>
```

With this I have managed to delete in the uninstall process and not be modified during the update, but the update process fails.

I have tried and read many solutions on the web but I do not get any of them working.